# Save image automatically with SchemDraw library

Tags: python

I want to use this library in python to generate electric diagrams:
https://cdelker.bitbucket.io/SchemDraw/,
and I want to run this code in the server.

The idea is generate the image, save it in the server and after give it to the client via an url.

I'm using its example code to test:

```
import SchemDraw as schem
import SchemDraw.elements as e
d = schem.Drawing()
V1 = d.add(e.SOURCE_V, label='10V')
d.add(e.RES, d='right', label='100K$\Omega$')
d.add(e.CAP, d='down', botlabel='0.1$\mu$F')
d.add(e.LINE, to=V1.start)
d.add(e.GND)
d.draw()
d.save('testschematic.svg')
```

It works ok, but the problem is that the image appears and I need to save it manually, and if I execute this code in the server, it gives me the error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1877, in
>   **init** api_1            |     self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use) api_1
>   | _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment
>   variable

I guess that is impossible shows an image in a server because it hasn't an visual interface.

Is there a possibility to save this, without showing it?

Comment: I have a similar issue.  It executes d.draw() and does not continue to d.save().  If I remove the d.draw(), this error appears:  AttributeError: 'Drawing' object has no attribute 'fig'

Comment: FYI, at least as of 0.7.1, `Drawing.save()` calls `Drawing.draw()` internally, so the extra call to `d.draw()` before `d.save()` is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The official docs now have a section for this: https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/start.html#server-side**

As of `schemdraw` 0.8, you can save the image `bytes` directly to a variable in memory without the need for a file or window pop up.

```py
from schemdraw import Drawing, ImageFormat
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') # Set the backend here

drawing = Drawing()
# Add circuit components here.

# Save the schematic bytes to a variable.
image_bytes = drawing.get_imagedata(ImageFormat.SVG)
```

---

For `schemdraw <= 0.7.1`:

Collin Delker, the SchemDraw author, provided this advice at https://www.collindelker.com/2014/08/29/electrical-schematic-drawing-python.html to change the matplotlib backend using [`matplotlib.use`](https://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html).

*SchemDraw draws on a Matplotlib figure, so if you have an interactive Matplotlib backend it will try to show the image in a window, which isn't possible on a server. Try setting the backend to something else, like "Agg", first, and see if this takes care of it:*

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') # Set the backend here

import SchemDraw as schem
import SchemDraw.elements as e
d = schem.Drawing()
...
d.draw()
d.save('mycircuit.svg')
```

It worked for me.

See also: [matplotlib FAQ What is a backend?](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

Comment: Yup, It was months ago, yes I solved it of that way, thanks for your response.